# PDF a DataFrame limpio

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio

buenos días ! les comento estoy leyendo información de un PDF y obtengo la siguiente información:

```
data <- c("514 9 1521222 CAPDEVILA, ENRIQUE L U I S 02, 00 815,65 16,31","518 9 1521222 LUCCHESI, BEATRIZ 02, 00 836,76 16,74",
      "519 9 1521221 CASTILLO ERNESTO RAFAEL 20-06645829-7 02,00 1.020,54 20,41", "525 6 1521210 BADA, ROSA 27-05794825-1 02, 00 731,71 14,63")
```

Luego esta información la convierto en un data frame dividido por columnas pero acá es donde surge el problema que la división de columnas no es del todo correcta.

```
tabla <- as.data.table(data)
tabla <- cSplit(tabla, "data", " ")
```

Les agradecería si me dan un consejo o ayuda. Gracias

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que el formato es totalmente variable. Tal vez puedas llegar a procesar las primeras tres columnas, pero a partir del nombre se complica todo. El espacio podría ser un separador, pero los nombres de por sí ya tienen espacios variables para separar cada nombre, además pareciera que en algunas filas faltara información (la cuit no aparece en todas las filas).  Además, fijate como está escrito `L U I S`, con un blanco por cada letra. LA extracción del PDF no parece ser la mejor para lo que buscas, si puedes comparte el PDF para ver si hay alguna alternativa.

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta, mira esta es una foto del pdf : https://ibb.co/cXXPMfN
Si el problema es que detecta como muchos espacios y no se si hay alguna manera de solucionar esto. El comando que utilice para extraer la info del pdf es :pdf_text("data.pdf") %>% strsplit(split = "\n")

Comment: Mira, si pudieras lograr leer el PDF sin remover espacios  entre las columnas, podrías leer el vector por posiciones fijas y sería mucho más sencillo. por lo que muestras en el vector que obtienes, la lectura solo deja un solo espacio espacio entre columna y columna.

Answer (score 0):

> Mira, si pudieras lograr leer el PDF sin remover espacios entre las
>   columnas, podrías leer el vector por posiciones fijas y sería mucho
>   más sencillo. por lo que muestras en el vector que obtienes, la
>   lectura solo deja un solo espacio espacio entre columna y columna. –
>   Patricio Moracho hace 1 hora.

Muchas gracias a Patricio, esa respuesta fue la que me sirvio